# Install KDE on kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, desktop-environment

I was trying to install KDE desktop environment on Kali Linux. So I used the following command:-

```
sudo apt-get install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base kde-plasma-desktop
```

And I got this  error :-

```
 Unable to locate package kde-plasma-desktop
```

Then i executed `sudo apt-get update` to update the repositories then again used the above mentioned command, but the same error occurred.

Can anyone explain how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Perfect Solution http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210073/install-kde-on-kali-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix sources list.

Run `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`  and paste the following in that file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20130315-11:02]/ kali contrib main non-free
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20130315-11:02]/ kali contrib main non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib

## Security updates
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Run `sudo apt-get update`

And now run:

`sudo apt-get install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base kde-plasma-desktop`

KDE will be installed on Kali Linux